# How can I avoid bad character appending in a list (Python)?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out why `isnumeric()` failed to detect bad characters like `³` and count it as a number.

My chunk of code:

```
words = input().upper()
char = []
digit = []

for i in range(0, len(words)):
    if words[i].isalpha():
        char.append(words[i])
    elif words[i].isnumeric():
        digit.append(words[i])
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Take a look at the [`str.isnumeric()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric). `³` would be counted as numeric.

Comment: ohhhh thanks that does answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because `str.is{numeric,alpha}()` checks characters to see if their type is a UTF character of type number which can result for example that a Chinese symbol of 2 being counted as a number. If you want to check against only ASCII numbers then you can use your own function:

```
nums = '0123456789'

words = input().upper()
char = []
digit = []

for i in range(0, len(words)):
    if words[i].isalpha():
        char.append(words[i])
    elif words[i] in nums:
        digit.append(words[i])
```

Also note that `isalpha` will return many other characters as alphabetic which you may not want to.

Comment: `nums` already exists in the `strings` module btw.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes but i guess this is faster and more simple rather than any imports.

Comment: Re *"UTF character"*: [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is an encoding. Do you mean "[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)" (or similar - "codecoint")?